# Create a showMenu behavior

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to reproduce in Flutter the behavior displayed in the video below, but I don't know how to do it. I know that it is necessary to use Widgets like: MouseRegion among others, but I can't evolve. Can anyone reproduce this behavior as shown in the video below? Has anyone ever done something like this?

[vídeo](https://youtube.com/shorts/CLW6GD1h34M?feature=share)

I hope I can reproduce the behavior of the video using flutter and dart.

Comment: This may help you https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a package like [easy_sidemenu](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_sidemenu).
With this package you could change the state of the drawer from Compact to Open. I hope this helps you get it done.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).